# Can protocol buffer parse a message in "debug string" format?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'd like to use protocol buffer in my program to read data from a file. I also would like to be able to edit the data file with any text editor, for a start (I'll write a data editor later on, and switch to full binary).

Is there a way to parse a human-readable format ? (debug string provided by protobuf itself, or some other format).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a text based format too, but support for this is implementation specific. For example, I don't support it *at all* in protobuf-net. But yes: such is defined, and discussed (for example) here: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format.html

Personally, I'd rather use binary and write a UI around the model.

Comment: Thanks ! This will do, as it's temporary. I don't need portability nor long term compatibility at this point, and I'll write an editor later if needed.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using command-line tools, the [Piqi project](http://piqi.org) includes [piqi convert](http://piqi.org/doc/tools/#piqiconvert) command for converting between 4 formats: binary Protocol Buffers, JSON, XML and [Piq](http://piqi.org/doc/piq). The Piq format is specially designed for viewing and editing data in a text editor.

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't specify the programming language, and my answer is only about Java.

In Java, a [`Message`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Message.html) instance's [`toString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Message#toString--) method returns a human-readable textual format. The same format can then be parsed into a `Message` instance by [`TextFormat.merge`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat#merge-java.lang.CharSequence-com.google.protobuf.Message.Builder-):

```
String messageString = ...
MyMessage.Builder builder = MyMessage.newBuilder();
TextFormat.merge(messageString, builder);
MyMessage newMessage = builder.build();
```

([Variations of the `merge` method](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat.html#merge-java.lang.Readable-com.google.protobuf.Message.Builder-) can also read from a stream, to avoid reading the whole message string into memory.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use ProtoBuf? You could use Json at first, and then switch to either Bson or MessagePack as a binary format.

The Json/Bson combination has the advantage that you can use the same library (Json.net) for them. I believe Bson is a bit bigger than ProtoBuf though.

Or you can use Json/MessagePack. Technically MessagePack is a better binary format than Bson/ProtoBuf IMO. But the tooling support is worse, and you'll need a seperate library for Json and MessagePack. It supports everything Json does and more(in particular it can use both string and integer keys in dictionaries).

Quick comparison of MsgPack and ProtoBuf:

- Resulting data size if similar constructs are used seems to be comparable.
- Encoding/Decoding performance largely depends on the implementation, but I expect it to be of similar magnitude
- MsgPack is more self describing. . In ProtoBuf you don't even see if something is a submessage or a blob.
- MsgPack supports non integer keys in a dictionary. One thing this allows is storing properties by name when you don't care about size and switch to integers where the gains are large.
- MsgPack stores the element count instead of the size for arrays/dictionaries. This has the advantage that you don't need to go back in the output and fit in the size all the time, making writing a serializer easier and possibly gives faster write speed. On the other hand you can't easily skip over an element because you don't know its size.
- MsgPack naturally supports a superset of Json, so you can migrate from Json easily.
- Tool support, documentation and popularity are much better with ProtoBuf. In particular ProtoBuf.net looks nicer than the C# code available for MsgPack.

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives, but I'll give a try to protobuf. All solutions seem quite alike, for my needs, so I just arbitrarily chose one.

Comment: I'm curious: what thugs in MsgPack do you see as better?

Comment: @Marc That's it more self describing is definitely a big plus. In ProtoBuf I don't even see if something is a submessage or a blob. Non integer dictionary keys is nice too. For The other differences are relatively minor, but in most of them I slightly prefer MsgPack.

Comment: don't forget, it could also be a string or packed array ;p (re blob / sub-message)

Comment: @Marc I don't care too much about the binary vs. string distinction. What I care about in this context is that I can run the protobuf reader without it knowing the DTD, and then work on its output without needing to go back to the protobuf reader.

Comment: @CodeInChaos hehehe if I *ever* finish protobuf-net (or at least, get happy enough with it), maybe I'll write a new output layer using MsgPack. Mainly just to prove a point ;p